# Why could glRasterPos2f not work?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013

i am trying to render a couple of tga files with opengl, using only glDrawPixels function and not texturing. I basically have the display loop, and manage to display the two files. After that i try to set the raster position on the x axis to the right, by declaring a global x GlInt variable and then incrementing it on each display loop. Thing is, this is not working. If i put an initial value to x, for example 100, the function will work and translate the images 100 pixels to the right, but incrementing it during the display loop doesn't do anything. Any ideas on what i could be doing wrong?

```
   //Aplicatia realizeaza deschiderea si afisarea unui fisier tga


#include "glos.h"
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <glaux.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
    GLbyte  identsize;              // Size of ID field that follows header (0)
    GLbyte  colorMapType;           // 0 = None, 1 = paletted
    GLbyte  imageType;              // 0 = none, 1 = indexed, 2 = rgb, 3 = grey, +8=rle
    unsigned short  colorMapStart;          // First colour map entry
    unsigned short  colorMapLength;         // Number of colors
    unsigned char   colorMapBits;   // bits per palette entry
    unsigned short  xstart;                 // image x origin
    unsigned short  ystart;                 // image y origin
    unsigned short  width;                  // width in pixels
    unsigned short  height;                 // height in pixels
    GLbyte  bits;                   // bits per pixel (8 16, 24, 32)
    GLbyte  descriptor;             // image descriptor
} TGAHEADER;
#pragma pack(8)

void myinit(void);

void CALLBACK myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h);
void CALLBACK display(void);
GLint x = 100;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Allocate memory and load targa bits. Returns pointer to new buffer,
// height, and width of texture, and the OpenGL format of data.
// Call free() on buffer when finished!
// This only works on pretty vanilla targas... 8, 24, or 32 bit color
// only, no palettes, no RLE encoding.


GLbyte *gltLoadTGA(const char *szFileName, GLint *iWidth, GLint *iHeight, GLint *iComponents, GLenum *eFormat)
    {
    FILE *pFile;            // File pointer
    TGAHEADER tgaHeader;        // TGA file header
    unsigned long lImageSize;       // Size in bytes of image
    short sDepth;           // Pixel depth;
    GLbyte  *pBits = NULL;          // Pointer to bits

    // Default/Failed values
    *iWidth = 0;
    *iHeight = 0;
    *eFormat = GL_BGR_EXT;
    *iComponents = GL_RGB8;

    // Attempt to open the file
    pFile = fopen(szFileName, "rb");
    if(pFile == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Read in header (binary)
    fread(&tgaHeader, sizeof(TGAHEADER), 1, pFile);


    // Get width, height, and depth of texture
    *iWidth = tgaHeader.width;
    *iHeight = tgaHeader.height;
    sDepth = tgaHeader.bits / 8;
    printf ("a citit fisierul %d\n",tgaHeader.height);
    // Put some validity checks here. Very simply, I only understand
    // or care about 8, 24, or 32 bit targa's.
   // if(tgaHeader.bits != 8 && tgaHeader.bits != 24 && tgaHeader.bits != 32)
   //    return NULL;

    // Calculate size of image buffer
    lImageSize = tgaHeader.width * tgaHeader.height * sDepth;
    printf ("a citit fisierul %d\n",lImageSize);
    // Allocate memory and check for success
    pBits = (GLbyte*)malloc(lImageSize * sizeof(GLbyte));
    if(pBits == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Read in the bits
    // Check for read error. This should catch RLE or other 
    // weird formats that I don't want to recognize
    if(fread(pBits, lImageSize, 1, pFile) != 1)
        {
        free(pBits);
        return NULL;
        }

    // Set OpenGL format expected
    switch(sDepth)
        {
        case 3:     // Most likely case
            *eFormat = GL_BGR_EXT;
            *iComponents = GL_RGB8;
            break;
        case 4:
            *eFormat = GL_BGRA_EXT;
            *iComponents = GL_RGBA8;
            break;
        case 1:
            *eFormat = GL_LUMINANCE;
            *iComponents = GL_LUMINANCE8;
            break;
        };


    // Done with File
    fclose(pFile);

    // Return pointer to image data
    return pBits;
    }

void myinit()
    {
    // Black background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
// Called to draw scene
void CALLBACK display(void)
    {
    GLbyte *pImage = NULL;
    GLbyte *pImage2 = NULL;
    GLint iWidth, iHeight, iComponents;
    GLenum eFormat;

    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Targa's are 1 byte aligned
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glLoadIdentity( );

    pImage = gltLoadTGA("C:\\Users\\calin.oana\\Desktop\\grafica\\ACSLAB6S\\loadtga\\321104_fishes.tga", &iWidth, &iHeight, &iComponents, &eFormat);
    glTranslatef(0.01, 0, 0);



    //glRasterPos2f(0.0, 0.0);
    // Draw the pixmap
    if(pImage != NULL)  
        glDrawPixels(iWidth, iHeight, eFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pImage);

    // Don't need the image data anymore
    free(pImage);
    pImage = gltLoadTGA("C:\\Users\\calin.oana\\Desktop\\grafica\\ACSLAB6S\\loadtga\\mata.tga", &iWidth, &iHeight, &iComponents, &eFormat);
    if (pImage != NULL)
        glDrawPixels(iWidth, iHeight, eFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pImage);
    free(pImage);

    glRasterPos2i(x, 0);
    x++;
    // Do the buffer Swap
    auxSwapBuffers();

    }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// For this example, it really doesn't matter what the 
// projection is since we are using glWindowPos
void CALLBACK myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
    {
    // Prevent a divide by zero, when window is too short
    // (you cant make a window of zero width).
    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    // Reset the coordinate system before modifying
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //glTranslatef(x++, 0, 0);
    // Set the clipping volume
    gluOrtho2D(0.0f, (GLfloat) w, 0.0, (GLfloat) h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();    

    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main program entrypoint
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    auxInitDisplayMode (AUX_DOUBLE | AUX_RGB );
    auxInitPosition (0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    auxInitWindow("OpenGL Image Loading");
    myinit();
    auxReshapeFunc (myReshape);
    auxMainLoop(display);
    return(0);
    }
```

Edit: i have found out what is wrong, the loop of the display function isnt properly happening.

Comment: Your code example is too narrow. Is this part of a function? Where is `x` declared?

Comment: it's a global variable, GLint x = 100; i put the whole code sample now